# How to I resolve the Traceback error for creating SQL Lite database and printing a hex for first row name&age in python 3?

Tags: python, sqlite, printing, tuples, hex

Trying to create an SQL database in Python and insert some basic data then return the hex value of the first row of name/age in the database and then print it in python but keep getting tuples error.

Thanks

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Exercise_Ages.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Ages''')

cur.executescript('''CREATE TABLE Ages (name VARCHAR(128), age INTEGER);
DELETE FROM Ages;
INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Trudie', 18);
INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Marley', 26);
INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Elshan', 17);
INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Reese', 32);
INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Lex', 31);
INSERT INTO Ages (name, age) VALUES ('Briagha', 16);''')

conn.commit()

sqlstr = 'SELECT hex(name || age) AS name FROM Ages ORDER BY age DESC LIMIT 10'


for row in cur.execute(sqlstr):
    print(str(row[0]), row[1])

cur.close()
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-63-ddbebe584cc3>", line 22, in <module>
    print(str(row[0]), row[1])

IndexError: tuple index out of range
```

Comment: You have only one field in your SELECT, so there is no `row[1]`.

Answer (score 0):

This `SELECT hex(name || age) AS name FROM Ages` retrieves a single column for each row, and you're trying to print the second column too with:

```
print(str(row[0]), row[1])
```

Just do the following:

```
print(str(row[0]))
```